# Expand a single column to a wide/model matrix format

Tags: r, reshape2

Suppose I have a column in a `matrix` or `data.frame` as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(col1=sample(letters[1:3], 10, TRUE))
```

I want to expand this out to multiple columns, one for each level in the column, with 0/1 entries indicating presence or absence of level for each row

```
newdf <- data.frame(a=rep(0, 10), b=rep(0,10), c=rep(0,10))
for (i in 1:length(levels(df$col1))) {
  curLetter <- levels(df$col1)[i]
  newdf[which(df$col1 == curLetter), curLetter] <- 1
}
newdf
```

I know there's a simple clever solution to this, but I can't figure out what it is.
I've tried `expand.grid` on `df`, which returns itself as is. Similarly `melt` in the `reshape2` package on `df` returned `df` as is. I've also tried `reshape` but it complains about incorrect dimensions or undefined columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy with `model.matrix`

```
model.matrix(~ df$col1 + 0)
```

The term `+ 0` means that the intercept is not included. Hence, you receive a dummy variable for each factor level.

The result:

```
   df$col1a df$col1b df$col1c
1         0        0        1
2         0        1        0
3         0        0        1
4         1        0        0
5         0        1        0
6         1        0        0
7         1        0        0
8         0        1        0
9         1        0        0
10        0        1        0
attr(,"assign")
[1] 1 1 1
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$`df$col1`
[1] "contr.treatment"
```

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, `model.matrix` is the most direct candidate here, but here, I'll present three alternatives: `table`, `lapply`, and `dcast` (the last one since this question is tagged [reshape2](/questions/tagged/reshape2).

#### `table`

```
table(sequence(nrow(df)), df$col1)
#     
#      a b c
#   1  1 0 0
#   2  0 1 0
#   3  0 1 0
#   4  0 0 1
#   5  1 0 0
#   6  0 0 1
#   7  0 0 1
#   8  0 1 0
#   9  0 1 0
#   10 1 0 0
```

#### `lapply`

```
newdf <- data.frame(a=rep(0, 10), b=rep(0,10), c=rep(0,10))
newdf[] <- lapply(names(newdf), function(x) 
    { newdf[[x]][df[,1] == x] <- 1; newdf[[x]] })
newdf
#    a b c
# 1  1 0 0
# 2  0 1 0
# 3  0 1 0
# 4  0 0 1
# 5  1 0 0
# 6  0 0 1
# 7  0 0 1
# 8  0 1 0
# 9  0 1 0
# 10 1 0 0
```

#### `dcast`

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, sequence(nrow(df)) ~ df$col1, fun.aggregate=length, value.var = "col1")
#    sequence(nrow(df)) a b c
# 1                   1 1 0 0
# 2                   2 0 1 0
# 3                   3 0 1 0
# 4                   4 0 0 1
# 5                   5 1 0 0
# 6                   6 0 0 1
# 7                   7 0 0 1
# 8                   8 0 1 0
# 9                   9 0 1 0
# 10                 10 1 0 0
```

Comment: I don't know if the multitude of ways to do things in R is a blessing or a curse.... :)